# MacOS asks for permission to Node parent process instead of child

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

Using *child_process* module I'm trying to spawn process which should ask for permissions, but MacOS asks for permissions for parent instead of spawned child.

For example when I'm running code below in terminal, MacOS will ask for permission for "Terminal.app" instead of child. Same thing happens with exec/execFile functions.

Real life example is to remove Microphone permissions from Google Chrome, run code below in Terminal and go to google meet. MacOS will ask for microphone permissions for Terminal.app instead of Google Chrome.

Is it possible to use child_process module and make MacOS ask for permissions for child?

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const APP_PATH = '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome';
spawn(APP_PATH, [], {
  detached: true,
  stdio: "ignore",
}).unref();
```

Comment: Add to options, `env: { title: 'childprocess'}`, the spawn process inherits most of the parent options, i'm curious if the title of the child process changes, if it does then it works as intended.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, MacOS asked for "Terminal.app" persmissions

Comment: Can you post the `APP_PATH` contents ?

Comment: It works with any application that needs permissions, I updated Question with Google Chrome example

Comment: I've put up a fiddle with a demo, it might give you an idea if it doesn't work. It's a mainApp that starts a detached instance of node which will spawn your APP_PATH. [https://jsfiddle.net/95et82bq/](https://jsfiddle.net/95et82bq/)

Comment: Thanks for trying but your snippet is not working in my case (I also tried with Chrome), I had to switch to shell: false to see anything spawning but OS is still asking for permissions to Terminal.app

Comment: Try using the fork method. It creates another NodeJS process with its own v8 context, that's completely independent from the parent process. Maybe the OS detects the childprocess as a subprocess of the parent and defaults to asking the parent for permissions?

I don't see why you're asking this, though. You could just write out the commands with elevated permissions to allow the child process to run scripts/run executables. Is there any particular reason why you need this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answer is here;

https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node

You have other options like `execFile`, `exec`, `fork` other than `spawn`.

Fork should run without any attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Open Chrome via apple script works.

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

spawn('osascript', ['-e', 'tell application "Google Chrome" to activate'], 
{
  detached: true,
  stdio: "ignore",
}).unref();
```

[image]